# Best Practice on adding unmanaged resources in Azure AKS.

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-aks, azure-container-service

There are a few resources we have questions about. But with all of them we don't want to have Kubernetes manage them.

I can't find the answer online, I have tried.

First is more specific. We want to not have AKS manage our MSSQL Database. When using a managed volume we noticed a significant hit to performance. Due to time issue we are going with a simple MSSQL server and disk. Should/Can we add these directly to the managed cluster or should we move these to another RG and use a VPN Gateway?

Second question is the same but more general, when adding a non managed resource what is the best practice way to connect it to the cluster resources? Another RG and VPN Gateway in, or just add them to the Cluster and add a service for communication?

Thanks in advance, we are new to the Kube ecosystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the MSSQL Database. If you DO NOT want Kubernetes to manage it.

You will want the mssql server and DB to live on another Resource Group and then

- Inside of the mssql server.
- Click on `Fireway/NV` in the sidebar
- Click `+ Add existing VN` in the center
- Follow the steps on the right to get them to talk to each other.
- If you have not added a rule to your MC Vnet, you will need to do this twice.

  - The first time sets up the rule (takes up to 15 minutes) the 2nd time add the VN
  - If you do not do this twice, you will not add the VN and it will fail!

Comment: Be very careful here! If you make any changes to the AKS resources (such as the vnet) future upgrade and/or scale operations may fail and you may have to recreate AKS from scratch to recover. Been there done that, not fun.

Comment: Was there a cause? This is the practice I got from the AKS people from Azure Tech Support. As long as you have the connect string and the rule is correct for the vnet, then you should be able to talk. What cause the complete lack of communication? The vnet rule is the only part that is sketch that I've found. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on what you have done. The dangerous part is "add a rule to your MC Vnet". We modified our MC vnet following tech support advise and got it working, but the next "az aks upgrade" failed on the MC vnet. Try it out with your changes in place. If you can scale up and down and upgrade to another AKS release you should be fine. If not, better to detect it early!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response!!! Upvoted to give you cred. We are still 10 months from any kind of release deadline so we aren't hurting for time and honestly I probably could have just used AppServices, so we can switch if things hit the fan.

When the next upgrade comes out for AKS I will update this post. I now have a Jira ticket to make sure I do it too! 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

AKS cannot manage anything except itself (well, it can create different resources to manage itself effectively, but no external resources like mssql), so the first part of the question doesnt make sense.

If you want other resources to interact with agent nodes you have to either put them into the same vnet or into external vnet and peer those together.